FOUC With inertiajs (SSR), Vite and SCSS
I am building an application using Laravel, inertiajs (SSR), Vite, Vue 3, and SCSS
I have pages and component and each page/component has its own style file and it is imported inside of this page/component.
When the page is reloaded it is displaying FOUC (Flash Of Unstyled Content).
What could possibly be the issue and how to solve it.
I tried to put the style file as vite asset in app.blade.php, but this doesn't work since we are using vue (when navigating between pages it only take the initial render style).
I also tried preloading the style with <Head> of inertia but it didn't help either.
Thank you.
